# SAP .selectItem In VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am trying to extract data from a selection results pan in SAP. When I use the script recorder I am given this statement.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          4","&Hierarchy"
```

When I run this code, I get an object not identified error. I would like to be able to loop through a variable (i) in place of the number 4 in this string, where it will select each item in the list.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this error and also make the .select item variable rather than stuck on 4?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for something like this

```
Option explicit 

dim i as long 

For i = 1 to 5
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem """          " & i & """,""&Hierarchy""
...
next i
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still resulted in the same 424 Error.